# Spring Batch (2.2) Java Config + Quartz as Scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

I am trying to code a batch job using Spring Batch Java configuration and Quartz as the scheduler.

Relevant code snippet for java configuration :-

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchProcessingConfig {

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
@Qualifier("theJob")
public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("theJobName")
            .start(jobStep()).build();
}

@Bean
public Step jobStep() {
    StepBuilder stepBuilder = stepBuilderFactory.get("stepName");
    SimpleStepBuilder<Person, Person> chunk = stepBuilder
            .<Person, Person> chunk(10);
    return chunk.reader(personeReader())                
            .processor(jobProcessor()).build();
}

    @Bean
public JobProcessor<Person, Person> invoiceRejobProcessorminderProcessor() {
    return new JobProcessor();
}
```

The job has been wired the ItemReader and ItemProcessor.

I am able to successfully Junit Test the Job/Step using **JobLauncherTestUtils** class.

Problem :-

1. How can I configure Quartz scheduler to run the above configured Job.

   All the samples & examples I could explore have created their own Job class by extending **QuartzJobBean** but I want my above configured Job to be scheduled for running.
2. How do I unit test the scheduler functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, when I had such a requirement

```
public class Schedule {
    public Schedule()throws Exception{
       SchedulerFactory sf=new StdSchedulerFactory();
       Scheduler sched=sf.getScheduler();
       sched.start();
       JobDetail jd=new JobDetailImpl("myjob",sched.DEFAULT_GROUP,QuartzJob.class);
       SimpleTrigger st=new SimpleTriggerImpl("mytrigger",sched.DEFAULT_GROUP,new Date(),
                  null,SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY,60L*1000L);
       sched.scheduleJob(jd, st);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
       try{
         new Schedule();
       }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

==================================

```
public class QuartzJob implements Job{

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
          String[] springConfig  = 
                {   
                    "resources\\spring-batch.xml" ,"SPRING_BATCH_JOB_NAME"
                };

            CommandLineJobRunner.main( springConfig );
            System.out.println("Done");

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't have any class that implements Job interface. How should I create JobDetail instance ?

Comment: This job is not spring batch job, but a quartz job. I hope you have your spring batch job configured in your xml? Use those in the springconfig array as I have shown above

Comment: Is is it even possible to use Quartz scheduler while configuring jobs as mentioned in question ?

Comment: I am not using XML config but Java config instead -@EnableBatchProcessing.

Comment: How are you running the spring batch job right now?

Comment: As of now only in Junit using JobLauncherTestUtils. In future I want to run/schedule job as soon as  my ApplicationContext/WebApplicationContext is up.

Comment: I am not sure, but can you check if you can put the code from JobLauncherUtils into a main method and run that in standalone?

Comment: It seems I have the same problem as a topicstarter - to match Quartz job and Spring Batch job for my configuration described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647018/how-should-i-use-tasklet-chunk-to-finish-job-succesfully. Why Quartz - because our app works on cluster environment, suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492788/spring-batch-on-clustered-environment-websphere. Could someone make a suggestion how to use Quartz job in Spring Batch?